# Could someone explain me what this shell bash command "echo{,}" means?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

If I do this:

`echo{,}`

The result is:

`echo`

I don't really understand the {,}  at the end and the result
Thanks to clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with something simpler to see how `{}` works: As @anubhava linked, it generates strings. Essentially, it expands all the elements in it and combines them with whatever is before and after it (space is separator if you don't quote).

Example:

```
$ bash -xc 'echo before{1,2}after and_sth_else'
+ echo before1after before2after and_sth_else
before1after before2after and_sth_else
```

Note that there is a space between `echo` and the arguments. This is not the case on what you have posted. So what happened there? Check the following:

```
$ bash -xc 'man{1,2}'
+ man1 man2
bash: man1: command not found
```

The result of the expansion is fed to bash and bash tries to execute it. In the above case, the command that is looking for is `man1` (which does not exist).

Finally, combine the above to your question:

- `echo{,}`

  - `{,}` expands to *two* empty elements/strings
  - These are then prefixed/concatenated with "echo" so we now have `echo echo`
  - Expansion finished and this is given to `bash` to execute
  - Command is `echo` and its first argument is "echo"... so it echoes echo!

Comment: Thanks @urban I now really understood it.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo{,}
```

is printing just `echo` because it is equivalent of `echo echo`.

More examples to clarify:

```sh
bash -xc 'echo{,}'
+ echo echo
echo

echo foo{,}
foo foo

echo foo{,,}
foo foo foo
```

> `More about Brace Expansion`

> Brace  expansion is a mechanism by which arbitrary strings may be generated.  This mechanism is similar to pathname expansion, but the filenames generated
> need not exist.  Patterns to be brace expanded take the form of an optional preamble, followed by either a series of comma-separated strings or a sequence
> expression  between  a  pair  of braces, followed by an optional postscript.  The preamble is prefixed to each string contained within the braces, and the
> postscript is then appended to each resulting string, expanding left to right.

Comment: ya, it's answered well also and @urban also explained to me very clearly. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

The `{item1,item2,...}` is a brace expansion.

So `echo{,}` is expanded as `echo echo` because `{,}` has two (empty) elements, then `echo` prints it argument.

Try this :

```sh
$ set -x
$ echo{,}
+ echo echo
echo
$ set +x
+ set +x
$
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also handy to generate "cross products" without nested loops:

```sh
$ ary=( {1,2,3}{a,b,c} )
$ declare -p ary
declare -a ary=([0]="1a" [1]="1b" [2]="1c" [3]="2a" [4]="2b" [5]="2c" [6]="3a" [7]="3b" [8]="3c")
```

Comment: Ya, thanks for this tip. The answer of @urban is very clear for me and now with your answer I can appreciate the kind of stuffs that we can do with it.